# How to select data without clicking on any button in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

The code is as follows

script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#like1").click(function() {
            $("#offer2").val(1);
            $("#like1").attr("src", "images/like_on.png");
            $("#unlike1").attr("src", "images/unlike_off.png");
        });
        $("#unlike1").click(function() {
            $("#offer2").val(2);
            $("#like1").attr("src", "images/like_off.png");
            $("#unlike1").attr("src", "images/unlike_on.png");
        });
        $("#like2").click(function() {
            $("#offer4").val(1);
            $("#like2").attr("src", "images/like_on.png");
            $("#unlike2").attr("src", "images/unlike_off.png");
        });
        $("#unlike2").click(function() {
            $("#offer4").val(2);
            $("#like2").attr("src", "images/like_off.png");
            $("#unlike2").attr("src", "images/unlike_on.png");
        });
        $("#update").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var video1 = $("#offer1").val();
            var rating1 = $("#offer2").val();
            var video2 = $("#offer3").val();
            var rating2 = $("#offer4").val();
            var dataString = 'video1=' + video1 + '&rating1=' + rating1 + '&video2=' + video2 + '&rating2=' + rating2;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: dataString,
                url: 'insert.php',
                success: function(data) {
                    //alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

body

```
<div id="content-area" >

    <br>
    <form name="frm" method="POST" action="">
        <div id="content-area1"> <p style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:14px;margin-left:8px;padding-top:18px;word-spacing:5px;" class="content-videos">HOW TO PUT ON YOUR ACUVUE BRAND CONTACT LENSES</p></div>
        <div id="content-video1area"><a href="play_video1.html"><img src="images/play_video.png" width="57" height="53" style="float:right; margin-right: 278px;margin-top: 77px;"/></a></div>
        <div id="content-area2"><p style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:14px;margin-left:15px;padding-top:22px;">HELPFUL?</p><img src="images/unlike_off.png" width="39" height="33" style="float:right; margin-right: 55px;margin-top: -23px;" id="unlike1"/><img src="images/like_off.png" width="39" height="33" style="float:right; margin-right: -83px;margin-top: -23px;" id="like1"/></div>
        <input type="hidden" name="offer1" id="offer1" value="1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="offer2" id="offer2" value="" />
        <br>
        <div id="content-area1"><p style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:14px;margin-left:8px;padding-top:18px;word-spacing:5px;" class="content-videos">HOW TO TAKE OFF YOUR ACUVUE BRAND CONTACT LENSES</p> </div>
        <div id="content-video2area"><a href="play_video2.html"><img src="images/play_video.png" width="57" height="53" style="float:right; margin-right: 278px;margin-top: 77px;"/></a></div>
        <div id="content-area2"><p style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:14px;margin-left:15px;padding-top:22px;">HELPFUL?</p><img src="images/unlike_off.png" width="39" height="33" style="float:right; margin-right: 55px;margin-top: -23px;" id="unlike2"/><img src="images/like_off.png" width="39" height="33" style="float:right; margin-right: -83px;margin-top: -23px;" id="like2"/></div>
        <input type="hidden" name="offer3" id="offer3" value="2" />
        <input type="hidden" name="offer4" id="offer4" value="" />


        <input type="hidden" name="name" id="name" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="last_name" id="last_name" value="" />
        <input type="submit" name="Update" id="update" value="Update" />
    </form>
</div>
```

php code to insert data

```
<?php
include('libraries/config.php');
  $video1 = $_POST['video1'];
  $rating1 = $_POST['rating1'];
  $video2 = $_POST['video2'];
  $rating2 = $_POST['rating2'];
  $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO videos(videoID,rating) VALUES ('$video1','$rating1')");
        $stmt->execute();
  $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO videos(videoID,rating) VALUES ('$video2','$rating2')");
        $stmt->execute();       
?>
```

here am able to insert the data but am able to insert when clicking update button, the data has to be inserted automatically without clicking any button is it possible, if so please help. and also I need to populate the data while coming to this page again. thanks

Comment: so how do want to save the data instead of clicking on update button.?

Comment: You need "an event" to trigger the update. What would you like it to be? A key is pressed? Someone finishes typing? Some time has elapsed?

Comment: normally in ui i should not have that update button, so am asking, i was so confused so

Comment: either clicking on other tabs or by clicking back button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the unload event:

```
$(window).unload(function(){
    var myData = {'var1':42, 'arg2':24};// Data for myScript.php
    $.post("myScript.php", myData, function(data) {
        console.log(data);// Result of myScript.php
    });
});
```

**EDIT**: Add this code juste before `</script>`. This code will call your update function.

```
$(window).unload(function(){
    $("#update").click({'preventDefault':function(){}});
});
```

Comment: is that  $("#update").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var video1 = $("#offer1").val();
            var rating1 = $("#offer2").val();
            var video2 = $("#offer3").val();
            var rating2 = $("#offer4").val();
            var dataString = 'video1=' + video1 + '&rating1=' + rating1 + '&video2=' + video2 + '&rating2=' + rating2;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: dataString,
                url: 'insert.php',
                success: function(data) {
                }
            });
        });

Comment: is that instead of above code i have to use what you have suggested

Comment: Yes it quite similar. But my event doesn't require any action from the user. See my edit

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as converting the  $("#update").click(function(e)

to a named function

```
function update(){
     e.preventDefault();
        var video1 = $("#offer1").val(); //etc.

}
```

Then add this inside each of your  'click' functions.

```
$("#like1").click(function() {
        $("#offer2").val(1);
        $("#like1").attr("src", "images/like_on.png");
        $("#unlike1").attr("src", "images/unlike_off.png");
        update();
    });
```